# For a library, GDB does only see source in header files, whereas source in .cpp files is not available

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, header-files

I am using `gdb` to debug a program compiled against a static library. Both the library and the program were compiled with debug symbols. **For this library, `gdb` does only see the source code implemented in `.h` files and not the source code implemented in `.cpp` files. I wonder why?**

- For example

  ```
  (gdb) info sources
  ```

  only lists header files from that library and no `.cpp` files.
- I am able to set breakpoint to some function that was implemented in a `.cpp` file. For example `gdb` understands this command:

  ```
  (gdb) break orgQhull::Qhull::runQhull,
  ```

  it is, however, not possible to debug the code inside the body of that function. (It is only possible to step through individual instructions on the assembler level using the `stepi` command.) On the other hand, the debuger is able to see the code of functions implemented in header files.
- The `backtrace` command reports that there is "No symbol table available" for the `runQhull` function mentioned earlier:

  ```
  (gdb) backtrace full

  #0  0x00000000004d361a in orgQhull::Qhull::runQhull(orgQhull::RboxPoints const&, char const*) ()
  No symbol table info available.
  #1  0x000000000049573a in ConvexHull::ConvexHull (this=0x7fffffffcb70, tree=..., begin=..., end=...)
      at /home/filip/fel/dp/sandbox/src/populating_octomap/include/ConvexHull.h:40
  ```

What could be the reason for this? Any suggestions are welcome!

**Some details:**

- The library in question is Qhull's `libqhullcpp.a` with sources at `git://gitorious.org/qhull/qhull.git`
- System: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS with GNU/Linux 3.2.0-40-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP x86_64
- gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
- GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

Comment: Is the library compiled in debug?

Comment: Have you included the library source directory in gdb source search path?

Comment: I am really sorry and I apologize. I have complied against wrong library archive. The debug version of the static library had been created with a suffix and I did not realize that. Mea culpa. Thank you for your help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the reason for this?

Either

- you've built the library *without* `-g` flag, or
- you've stripped the library after it was built (this is very unlikely).

Check your library build log. You *believe* you built it with `-g`, but you are *very* likely mistaken.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your time. I am really sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: I have compiled against wrong library archive. I am using CMake to build both the library and my program. The **debug version** of the library **had been created with a suffix** and I did not realize that. The non-debug version was named `libqhullcpp.a` and it stayed in the build directory even after `make clean`. The version built with `-g` was named `libqhullcpp_d.a`. It seems like it is not a good idea to change the build type `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` in an existing build directory?

Comment: Should I add [cmake] tag to the question? Should I modify it in order to make it more useful for other users? Or should I create another question/answer pair instead? What would be preferred here on SO?